# asp.net mvc @Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have checkboxes in my form
[image]

I added at my model

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace CorePartners_Site2.Models
 {
public class CareerForm
     {
    //....
    public List<CheckBoxes> EmploymentType { get; set; } 
      }
 }

 public class CheckBoxes
 {
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public bool Checked { get; set; }
 }
```

and added at my form

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.EmploymentType, new { id = "employmentType_1" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.EmploymentType, new { id = "employmentType_2" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.EmploymentType, new { id = "employmentType_3" })
```

but I get the mistake
[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`CheckBoxFor` takes a `bool`, you're passing a `List<CheckBoxes>` to it. You'd need to do:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmploymentType.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EmploymentType[i].Checked, new { id = "employmentType_" + i })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmploymentType[i].Text)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EmploymentType[i].Text)
}
```

Notice I've added a `HiddenFor` for the `Text` property too, otherwise you'd lose that when you posted the form, so you wouldn't know which items you'd checked.

Edit, as shown in your comments, your `EmploymentType` list is `null` when the view is served. You'll need to populate that too, by doing this in your action method:

```
public ActionResult YourActionMethod()
{
    CareerForm model = new CareerForm();

    model.EmploymentType = new List<CheckBox>
    {
        new CheckBox { Text = "Fulltime" },
        new CheckBox { Text = "Partly" },
        new CheckBox { Text = "Contract" }
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: @Heidel Yeah inside your form

Comment: I tried, but I got this [http://i.imgur.com/Q78xcBD.png](http://i.imgur.com/Q78xcBD.png). what's wrong?

Comment: Should I add at my model something?

Comment: @Heidel Check my edit, you need to populate the `EmploymentType` list.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! And explain me, please, how can I set name for my checkboxes, because now I get like `<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Требуется поле Checked." id="employmentType_1" name="EmploymentType[0].Checked" type="checkbox" value="true">`

Comment: @Heidel The name has to be like that, so that when you post the form the model binder can correctly bind back to your list.

Comment: @Rob A `foreach` won't work if you're posting the form. This is because when using lists and arrays and posting them back, they need to be correctly indexed i.e. `Model.List[index].Property` in order for the model binder to bind those values to the list values.

Answer (score 3):

`Html.CheckBoxFor` expects a `Func<TModel, bool>` as the first parameter.  Therefore your lambda must return a `bool`, you are currently returning an instance of `List<Checkboxes>`:

```
model => model.EmploymentType
```

You need to iterate over the `List<Checkboxes>` to output each checkbox:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmploymentType.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmploymentType[i].Text)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EmploymentType[i].Checked, 
              new { id = string.Format("employmentType_{0}", i) })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmploymentType.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmploymentType[i].Text)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EmploymentType[i].Checked, new { id = "YourId" })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If only one checkbox should be checked in the same time use RadioButtonFor instead:

```
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Type,1, new { @checked = "checked" }) fultime
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Type,2) party
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Type,3) next option...
```

If one more one could be checked in the same time use excellent extension: [CheckBoxListFor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-A-missing-MVC-extension):

Hope,it will help