# Converting checkbox result into model's value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET project and I have some checkbox to select the recurrence. I want to convert that to a string that will display it.

A simple version is

Create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
       <p style="font-weight:bold">New Record</p>
            <div id="date">
                <input type="checkbox" value="Sunday" />Sunday
                <input type="checkbox" value="Monday" />Monday
                <input type="checkbox" value="Tuesday" />Tuesday
                ...
            </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

        <div align="left">
           <font color="black" size="4" > @Html.ActionLink("<<Back to List", "Index", "Home", null, null)</font>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And I want to save it in the model as a simple string like "1011011"

Standard Create function

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Event event)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var context = new EventDBContext())
        {
            context.RecordList.Add(event);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View("Index");

    }
    return View("Error");
}
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the `CheckBoxFor` [Input extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830433(v=vs.118).aspx)

[There are all sorts of walkthroughs on using them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688170/asp-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)