# checkbox values not displaying in view properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I previously had a view that contained as follows:

```
<tr>
            <th class="editAddLabel">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsShellFish, "Allergic to Shellfish")
            </th>
            <td class="editAddField">
                @Html.CheckBox("IsShellFish")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="editAddLabel">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsPeaNut, "Allergic to Peanuts")
            </th>
            <td class="editAddField">
                @Html.CheckBox("IsPeaNut")
            </td>
        </tr>
```

and it worked perfectly. I then made some changes to my project and wanted to use two different models in one view so I put the original model that was binded to the view and a second model in a ViewModel class, and eventually changed those lines of code to the following:

```
<tr>
    <th class="editAddLabel">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.personVM.IsShellFish, "Allergic to Shellfish")
    </th>
    <td class="editAddField">
        @Html.CheckBox("personVM.IsShellFish")
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="editAddLabel">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.personVM.IsPeaNut, "Allergic to Peanuts")
    </th>
    <td class="editAddField">
        @Html.CheckBox("personVM.IsPeaNut")
    </td>
</tr>
```

All my non-checkbox model properties are displaying normally and seem unaffected, but the checkbox ones do not display properly on the view whenever I want a user to edit their information. I know the properties are being passed properly from the view to the model when checked, and when I send the viewmodel back to the view it shows the correct boolean values for the fields corresponding to the views, so I feel like it must be something in my view's code that results in all the checkboxes being unchecked despite the fact that their values might be true. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16688321/3514288

Comment: You really should use a strongly typed helper  `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.personVM.IsShellFish)`

Comment: As a side note, you should rename those allergy properties. `IsShellfish` implies that the person may be a shellfish. I know this is a silly remark, but it's best practice to make your code self-documenting. `HasShellfishAllergy` is much clearer.

Comment: @AlexArt. this is kinda late. I tried what you said and got the following errors: Error 11 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: and alsoError 12 Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<PrgComp_Competition.ViewModel.RegisterStudentViewModel,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: since `IsShellFish` is `bool?` and not a `bool` you can use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.personVM.IsShellFish)` which will generate a drop down with 3 values (empty/true/false)

Comment: @AlexArt. that worked. I wonder why it didn't work with a checkbox though

Comment: because checkbox expects bool and not bool?

Comment: I tried to casting it by doing @Html.CheckBoxFor((bool)model => model.personVM.IsShellFish) but then it says Error 11 The name 'model' does not exist in the current context. I'd really like to use a checkbox =/

Comment: Than you need to change IsShellFish to bool insted of bool?

Comment: @AlexArt. I fixed the problem by doing  @Html.CheckBox("personVM.IsShellFish", (bool)Model.personVM.IsShellFish)

Comment: Not sure why it worked but whatever