# Fill ViewModel collection from multiple fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in which user can select which shipping methods they want to support for they product that they are selling, e.g. first class letter, second class letter, parcel, etc. I only give users a collection of possible shipping methods, they declare how much each one will cost, so if someone wants to sell a toaster in a parcel, they will charge less than for a set of dumbbells.

My `ProductViewModel`:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public ICollection<SelectedShippingMethodViewModel> SelectedShippingMethods { get; set; }
```

And `SelectedShippingMethodViewModel`:

```
public class SelectedShippingMethodViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

In my form I create a section with possible options like this:

```
<h3>Add new product</h3>
<hr />
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNew", "ProductCreator", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Shipping methods</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @foreach (ShippingMethod shippingMethod in ViewBag?.ShippingMethods)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        // I don't know what should be here
                        @Html.CheckBox("SelectedShippingMethods", false)
                        @shippingMethod.Name
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        // I don't know what should be here
                        @Html.TextBox("SelectedShippingMethods.Price")
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add product</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I have a database table with every possible shipping method that I acquire like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddNew()
{
    ViewBag.ShippingMethods = await _shippingService.GetAllShippingMethodsAsync();
    return View();
}
```

The problem is if checkbox is selected I have to bind `Price` and `Name` for each individual `SelectedShippingMethodViewModel` and I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: You cannot bind a checkbox to collection of `SelectedShippingMethodViewModel` which is  what `SelectedShippingMethods`. And your textbox cannot bind to anything in your model either. Its not clear really clear what your trying to do here - what is the method this form posts to?

Comment: use `for` loop instead of `foreach`. Otherwise, form controls won't be created with proper `name` attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc @Html.CheckBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688170/asp-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)

Comment: @adiga, I want to bind 3 fields, not only a checkbox. Checkbox is really just to ignore shipping methods that are not selected. I can add additional `bool` field to my model, but the main problem of binding name and price is still there.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's 3 or 10 properties. Just add a `TextBoxfor()` for the `Price` property inside the loop.

Comment: @adiga But for which property. I want to bind 3 properties into single `SelectedShippingMethodViewModel` model which sits inside `ProductViewModel` as a collection, because there are multiple shippingMethods, so I have a collection. Please be precise.

Comment: Change `SelectedShippingMethods` to `ShippingMethods`. Loop in your controller and get the items which have the checked boolean as true and save them to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view models are incorrect. To allow users to select the shipping methods they want and add a price, that view model needs to be

```
public class ShippingMethodViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } // your checkbox binds to this property
}
```

and the `ProductViewModel` should be

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....
    public List<ShippingMethodViewModel> ShippingMethods { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the GET method, initialize your `ProductViewModel` and populate the `ShippingMethods` based on all available `ShippingMethods`, for example

```
var shippingMethods = await _shippingService.GetAllShippingMethodsAsync()
ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel
{
    ....
    ShippingMethods = shippingMethods.Select(x => new ShippingMethodViewModel
    {
        Name = x.Name
    }).ToList()
};
return View(model);
```

and in the view, use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` for typeof `ShippingMethodViewModel` to correctly generate your form controls

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ShippingMethods.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShippingMethods[i].IsSelected, Model[0].ShippingMethods.Name)  
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShippingMethods[i].IsSelected)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShippingMethods[i].Price)       
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ShippingMethods[i].Price)

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ShippingMethods[i].Name) // if you want this to be submitted as well
}
```

Then in the POST method

```
public ActionResult AddNew(ProductViewModel model)
{
     // Get the selected Shipping Methods and the associated price
     var selectedMethods = model.ShippingMethods.Where(x => x.Selected);
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought of setting names in `Get`.

Comment: I also assume that `ShippingMethods` would have a `Id` (PK) property which you would want to include in your view model and in the view as a hidden input

Comment: I have also rolled back your edit (please do not change your original question which invalidates comments and answers that have been added)

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to clarify my problem by removing misleading sentences in my question.